# Function to replicate the md5 function in PHP with vb.net

Tags: php, vb.net

I'm trying to duplicate the functionality of the PHP md5 function with vb.net, my client and server scripts need to be to apply the same hash function to values passed. This is what i've come up with, but it isn't matching php md5

```
  Public Function hashPassword(ByVal input As String) As String
        Dim salt As String = "asdf"
        Dim x As New System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
        Dim bs As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input + salt)
        bs = x.ComputeHash(bs)
        Dim s As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        For Each b As Byte In bs
            s.Append(b.ToString("x2"))
        Next
        Dim password As String = s.ToString()
        Return password
    End Function
```

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5.aspx#Y2132  Also, are you using the same salt in PHP as you are here in VB?

Comment: As Jonathan wrote read the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5.aspx and you can try this implementation: http://blog.brezovsky.net/en-text-2.html